# Were there commercials in the original broadcast of the moon landings, and how much did they go for?

Tags: spaceflight, television

I was pondering the future value of advertisements on the live broadcast of the inevitable eventual Mars landing, and it led me to wonder about this.

Comment: Interesting question - but you will have to clarify just what you mean. There were long periods of inactivity at times, such as in the initial orbit of the moon as they passed around the back side. Are you counting those, or just during the moonwalk itself? Neil Armstrong's landing was very tense, so there wouldn't have been any commercials **during** that, but before and after probably.

Comment: Where in the world? Not every television station is/was commercial so not every station covering the landings showed commercials.

Comment: I guess primarily before and after the moonwalk.

Comment: As for the second question, I guess I’m mostly referring to whichever stations were most watched in first world countries like the US and Western Europe, even if the answer is then “the most watched station had no commercials.”

Comment: @Aerovistae - you should add more details to the question, not just in comments, as to what country are you referring and even to what specific stations. The event was broadcast live in many countries including the Soviet camp.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Please do not reply in comments.  All issues ues raised in comments should be answered _in the question_.

Comment: [Related](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/how-did-nasa-achieve-their-live-tv-broadcast-in-1969) on some of the underlying technology employed.

Comment: Anyone with access to [Marketing the Moon](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/marketing-moon) by Scott and Jurek at their local library might find details about an answer in there.

Comment: [Here is the original CBS network coverage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E96EPhqT-ds) of the Apolloc 11 landing and moon walk. It includes no commercial breaks - but I wouldn't expect any. However local affiliates might well have inserted some depending on their contract with the network.

Answer (score 2):

It very much depends about which country you're asking. I am Dutch, in those days we didn't have advertisements in programs. Only short blocks before and after the news. 'American' in-program advertisements and 24/7 broadcasting came much later, mid or late 70's, if I recall correctly.

As far as I know in 1969 in-program advertisements, certainly for a major event like that, were not done. It would probably have caused an outcry back then. We have digressed/progressed *(pick your choice)* a lot since then.

Comment: This makes me wonder in how many countries the broadcast was "live".

Comment: I don't know. I was 9 at the time, we just got TV. I was allowed - very exceptional - to stay up late, to watch the landing. It was very late in the evening for us. So it was broadcasted live on Dutch TV.